# stop() function not working on actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have an actionscript 2.0 program that goes through a sequence of frames stepping on eah one using the function stop()

I'm compiling the same script on flash cs 5, that only supports actionscript 3.0, and when running the script the stop() function is ignored

any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Flash CS5 does support AS2. Go to the Publish Settings (File / Publish Settings) and go to the Flash Tab. On the top of the panel you must be able to set the target Player version and ActionScript version.

Good luck,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

`stop();` on a frame action works perfectly with AS3.  You seem to have some other problem causing the script to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the JVM's memory to get the desired result. I had the same issue and it worked for me when I increased it from 128MB to 512MB. If still not working there must be an issue with `actionscript` and you need to recheck it.

To Increase JVM memory :

1. Go to your Flash CS5 installed folder/en_US\Configuration\your ActionScript
   folder
2. Open jvm.ini
3. Change -Xmx128m to -Xmx512m

**Note:** If increasing the JVM's memory does not work. Before checking the `actionscript` code try to work the same code on another system with a bigger RAM size than yours.